# Angular2 ngBusy not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I updated my angular 2 to version 4.0.3 then ng busy stoped working and i got this exception:

> ERROR Error: Found the synthetic property @fadeInOut. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.

My ts component code:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {AdminService} from "../../../services/admin.service";
import {HttpService} from "../../../../http.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {Http, Response, Headers,RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-form',
  templateUrl: './products-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductsFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   product:any = {'needTransformer':'Yes', 'power':'', 'cct':'', 'cri':'', 'lightSource':'', 'country':'','category':{}, 'productionCompany':{},'finish':{}};

   companies: string[] =[];
   companiesSubscription: Subscription;

   finishes: string[] = [];
   finishesSubscription: Subscription;

   categories: string[] = [];
   categoriesSubscription: Subscription;

   lightSources: string[] = [];
   lightSourcesSubscription: Subscription;

   countries: string[] = [];
   countriesSubscription: Subscription;

   routeSubscritpion: Subscription;

   selectedCategory: string;
   selectedFinish: string;
   selectedProductionCompany: string;
   selectedLightSource: string;
   selectedCountry: string;
   selectedTransformerNeeded: string;
   isEdit: boolean = false;

  @ViewChild('mainImage')  mainImage: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('diemsnions')  diemsnions: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('effects')  effects: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('pdf')  pdf: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('categoryEl') categoryEl: ElementRef;

  busy: any;
  constructor(private httpService:HttpService, private adminService: AdminService, private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.busy = true;
    this.routeSubscritpion = this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
      let code = param['code'];
      if(code !='undefined')
        this.httpService.getProductDataByCode(code).subscribe(
        (data:any)=> {
         this.product=data;
         this.isEdit = true;
         this.selectedCategory = data.category.name;
         this.selectedFinish = data.finish.name;
         this.selectedCountry = data.country;
         this.selectedProductionCompany = data.productionCompany.name;
         this.selectedLightSource = data.lightSource;
         this.selectedTransformerNeeded = data.transformerNeeded;
         // this.categoryEl.nativeElement.value = data.category.name;
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
      );


    });

    this.companiesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllCompanies().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        data.forEach((entry)=> {
          this.companies.push(entry.name);
        });
        if(this.companies.length > 0)
          this.product.productionCompany = this.companies[0];
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.categoriesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllCategories().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        data.forEach((entry)=> {
          this.categories.push(entry.name);
        });
        if(this.categories.length > 0)
          this.product.category = this.categories[0];
      },
        (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.finishesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllFinishes().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        data.forEach((entry)=> {
          this.finishes.push(entry.name);
        });
        if(this.finishes.length > 0)
          this.product.finish = this.finishes[0];
      },
        (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.lightSourcesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllLightSources().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        this.lightSources = data;
        if(this.lightSources.length > 0)
          this.product.lightSource = this.lightSources[0];
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );

    this.lightSourcesSubscription = this.httpService.getAllCountries().subscribe(
      (data:any)=> {
        this.countries = data;
        if(this.countries.length > 0)
          this.product.country = this.countries[0];
      },
      (err)  => console.error(err+"<-------------"),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );
  }
  formatStrings(str)
  {
    str=str.replace(/\s/g, '');
    str=str.replace(/,/g, '');
    str=str.toUpperCase();
    return str
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm)
  {
    var values=form.value;
    let parent=this;

    let obj={
      name:values.name,
      description:values.description,
      code:values.code,
      category:{
        name:values.categories
      },
      productionCompany:{
        name:values.productionCompany
      },
      finish:{
        name:values.finish
      },
      transformerNeeded:values.transformerNeeded,
      power:values.power,
      cct:values.cct,
      cri:values.cri,
      ik: values.ik,
      ip: values.ip,
      luminous: values.luminous,
      optic: values.optic,
      lightSource:values.lightSource,
      country:values.productionContry,
      effictImagePath:'',
      normalImagePath:'',
      detailsImagePath:'',
      catalogPath:''

    };


    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,'Authorization': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))['token']});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    if(!this.isEdit) {


      this.busy = this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/products/', JSON.stringify(obj), options).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          parent.upload(obj.code)
        },
        (err) => console.error(err + "<-------------"),
        () => console.log("")
      );
    } else {
      obj.effictImagePath = this.product.effictImagePath;
      obj.normalImagePath = this.product.normalImagePath;
      obj.detailsImagePath = this.product.detailsImagePath;
      obj.catalogPath = this.product.catalogPath;
      this.busy = this.http.put('http://localhost:8090/products/'+obj.code, JSON.stringify(obj), options).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          parent.upload(obj.code)
        },
        (err) => console.error(err + "<-------------"),
        () => console.log("")
      );
    }


    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.companiesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.finishesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.lightSourcesSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  changeFinish(finish) {
    this.product.finish = finish;
    console.log(this.product);
  }

  makeFileRequest(url:string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let mainImageEl: HTMLInputElement = this.mainImage.nativeElement;
      let formData = new FormData();
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (mainImageEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("normalImagePath", mainImageEl.files.item(0), mainImageEl.files.item(0).name);

      let diemsnionsEl: HTMLInputElement = this.diemsnions.nativeElement;
      if (diemsnionsEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("detailsImagePath", diemsnionsEl.files.item(0), diemsnionsEl.files.item(0).name);

      let effectsEl: HTMLInputElement = this.effects.nativeElement;
      if (effectsEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("effictImagePath", effectsEl.files.item(0), effectsEl.files.item(0).name);

      let pdfEl: HTMLInputElement = this.pdf.nativeElement;
      if (pdfEl.files.length > 0)
        formData.append("catalogPath", pdfEl.files.item(0), pdfEl.files.item(0).name);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
          } else {
            reject(xhr.response);
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))['token']);
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }
  upload(code: string) {
    this.busy = this.makeFileRequest("http://levelskw.com/products/upload/"+code).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  }
}
```

Html code :

```
<div [ngBusy]="busy"></div>
  <div class="main-container">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <div fxLayout="column"  fxLayoutGap="15px">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="29px">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px">
          <div fxLayout="column" class='titleSection'>
            <div class="header"><div class='header-label'>Header</div></div>
            <div class='title'><input type="text" placeholder="Code" name="code" [(ngModel)]="product.code" /></div>
            <div class='title'><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" /></div>
            <div class="description"><textarea placeholder="Description" name="description" [(ngModel)]="product.description"></textarea></div>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column" class="loadSection">
            <div class="header"><div class='header-label'>Images</div></div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">Main image</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <input type="file" #mainImage/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">Dimensions</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <input type="file" #diemsnions/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">Effects</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <input type="file" #effects/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" class="img-section" fxLayoutGap="2px">
              <div class="img-lable">PDF</div>
              <div class="img-btn">
                <button fxLayoutAlign="center center">Upload</button>
                <input type="file" #pdf/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="column" class="details" fxLayoutGap="10px">
          <div class="header"><div class='header-label'>Related Products</div></div>
          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Category</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="categories" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory">
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category">{{category}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Manufactured By</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="productionCompany" [(ngModel)]="selectedProductionCompany">
                <option *ngFor="let company of companies" [ngValue]="company">{{company}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Materials</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="finish" [(ngModel)]="selectedFinish">
                <option *ngFor="let finish of finishes" [ngValue]="finish">{{finish}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Transformer needed</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="transformerNeeded" [(ngModel)]="selectedTransformerNeeded">
                <option value="true" selected>Yes</option>
                <option value="false" >No</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Power(W)</div>
              <input type="text"  name="power" [(ngModel)]="product.power"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>CCT(K)</div>
              <input type="text"  name="cct" [(ngModel)]="product.cct"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>IK</div>
              <input type="text"  name="ik" [(ngModel)]="product.ik"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Index of protection</div>
              <input type="text"  name="ip" [(ngModel)]="product.ip"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Luminous</div>
              <input type="text"  name="luminous" [(ngModel)]="product.luminous"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Optic</div>
              <input type="text"  name="optic" [(ngModel)]="product.optic"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>CRI</div>
              <input type="text"  name="cri" [(ngModel)]="product.cri"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Light Source</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="lightSource" [(ngModel)]="selectedLightSource">
                <option *ngFor="let lightSource of lightSources" [ngValue]="formatStrings(lightSource)" >{{lightSource}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div class="item-cont">
              <div class='lable'>Production country</div>
              <select class="dropdown" name="productionContry" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
                <option *ngFor="let company of countries" [ngValue]="formatStrings(company)" >{{company}}</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='control-btn-container'>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
          <button class="btn cancel" fxLayoutAlign="center center">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn save" fxLayoutAlign="center center">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>


   </form>
    </div>
```

pakage.json

```
{
  "name": "levels",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.2",
    "angular2-busy": "https://github.com/dinusuresh/angular2-busy.git",
    "angular2-spinner": "^1.0.9",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "md2": "0.0.17-2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-file-uploader": "^0.1.4",
    "ng2-material-select": "^0.1.8",
    "ngx-uploader": "^2.2.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "~2.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.3.0",
    "karma": "1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.2"
  }
}
```

root folder :
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error clearly stated that there you need to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`, that happened since Angular 4 release animations module has been moved out from `@angular/core`. It has been moved out to separate module `@angular/platform-browser/animations`. Apart from that you have to specify below mapping in case you're using `systemjs` module loader

```
'@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
'@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
```

Then do import `BrowserAnimationsModule` inside `app.module.ts` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` module. And then put it inside `imports` option of `AppModule`

[**Breaking Change**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#installing-rc1) from changelog.

Comment: i did it but i got this error :Unexpected module 'BrowserAnimationsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: @mohammad did you updated your all packages by command like I suggested a reference link in my answer..

Comment: i did npm istall @angular/platform-browser/animations --save i dont know where i should put the mapings ? in which folder

Comment: @mohammad what you're using as module loader??

Comment: how i can know  ?

Comment: I sounds like you are trying to `declare` the BrowserAnimationModule` in your `AppModule`. This is wrong because you do not own it. You need to `import` it instead.

Comment: @mohammad if your root folder has systemjs.config.js then its `systemjs` & if you have webpack.config.js then its `webpack`

Comment: it has karma.conf.js and protractor.conf.js i added the screenshot of my folder

Comment: @mohammad I got it, it is angular-cli which has inbuilt webpack

Comment: so what i can do now ?

Comment: @mohammad you should follow the instructructions given [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) for animations

Comment: thank you very much, i appreciate your effort with me  so much